# Cannot resolve symbol 'AbstractProducedQuery'

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to upgrade Spring Boot v2.7.3 to v3.1.1 and facing error - **Cannot resolve symbol 'AbstractProducedQuery'.**

Code line:
AbstractProducedQuery<?> abstractProducedQuery = query.unwrap(AbstractProducedQuery.class);

If 'AbstractProducedQuery' class is deprecated what is the replacement for 'AbstractProducedQuery'?